# How to save different array data in cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp

My array is something different from normal cakephp array.
now i want to save this data array using foreach loop.

```
[Data] => Array
        (
            [type_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 3
                )

            [data_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 1
                )

            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 213
                    [2] => 212
                    [3] => 23343
                )

            [amount] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 121
                    [1] => 342
                    [2] => 45454
                    [3] => 3243
                )

        )
```

i just want to a loop of foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to restructure your array first and then use `saveMany()` to save the restructured array:-

```
$data = array();
foreach ($array['ProductCharge'] as $col => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $data[$key]['ProductCharge'][$col] = $val;
    }
}

$this->ProductCharge->saveMany($data);
```

It is better to use `saveMany()` than save each record in a `foreach` loop.

There is possibly a [Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) method for restructuring the data without the need for the `foreach` loops, but can't think which would work as desired.

Comment: surely Hash method magic w'd have done justice here. your answer looks somehow opaque. good one nontheless

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which approach you've tried so far.

But `$this->Model->saveMany($arrayVariable)` should be just ok to save your data.